# Adding parallax effect to multiple banners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have 5 banners that I would like to add a translate/parallax effect to. I am using translate transform to slowly move the background image of the banner against the text that is on top of the banner. The javascript I have now works perfectly for the first banner image, but causes the parallax effect to start too early for the remaining banners, which causes the other banner images to move too down. How can I get the remaining banners to start the translate effect as I scroll down to them?

HTML:

```
<section class="banner-1">
     <div class="hero-bg"></div>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
         </div>
     </div>
</section>

<section class="banner-2">
     <div class="hero-bg"></div>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
         </div>
     </div>
</section>

<section class="banner-3">
     <div class="hero-bg"></div>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
         </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var calc = String(scrollPos/10);

    if (scrollPos > lastScrollTop) {
        $(".hero-bg").css({
            transform: 'translate3d(0px,'+calc+'px, 0)'
        });
    } 
    else {
        $(".hero-bg").css({
            transform: 'translate3d(0px,'+calc+'px, 0)'
        });
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrollPos;
});
```